# React real-time data-saving?

Tags: reactjs, real-time

So, I am a Javascript developer and I ove using React fr all kinds of things but I faced a big stone. Our application has a form which has many many inuts, checkboxes and so if a user starts filling in he will lose about 10 minutes only filling in, if in that time the connection stops or if some kind of networkerror occurs all his inputs will be gone, puff... So I wan to make something which makes AJAX requests everytime and input is filled in that form, so it will be networkerrorproof, can I use React for such a task and would it be efficient? I mean React has state and this state is always updated with the inputs values. Does that mean that when the user has network issue and can sense it, wrap thing up and send them to the browser or because his network is doomed I can't do anything?

Comment: If you have a network problem an AJAX request will also fail. I would consider using local storage (so it's saved right in the browser) if the state is so important.